# Django: writing text from uploaded file to text field

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I have the following model:

```
class Clean(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cv = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    cvfile = models.FileField()
```

I am trying to write the contents of `cvfile` to `cv` when the user submits the name and file from the form. I'm sure this can be done as the file and text field will be in the same object. The file will always be .txt so I assume a simple .read() can be performed.

Should I have a function that the form calls to perform this? If so how can this be done?

```
def writeCV(self):
        get_text = cvfile.open().read()
        #write to cv field somehow

        return self.cv
```

I am using django 1.9

**Traceback from Messaoud's answer:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cleaner/clean/add/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['cleaner.apps.CleanerConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  255.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  221.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in form_valid
  200.         self.object = form.save()

File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in save
  451.             self.instance.save()

File "C:\Users\barry\Desktop\College\Year 4\Semester 2\cvCleaner\cvcleaner\cleaner\models.py" in save
  11.         get_text = self.cvfile.open().read()

Exception Type: AttributeError at /cleaner/clean/add/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by overriding `save` method in your `Model`

```
class Clean(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cv = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank = True, null = True)
    cvfile = models.FileField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        get_text = self.cvfile.open().read()
        self.cv = get_text
        super(Clean, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
```

Or by Using [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-save) signal

```
def writeCV(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    get_text = instance.cvfile.open().read()
    instance.cv = get_text
    instance.save()
post_save.connect(writeCV, sender=Clean)
```

Comment: thanks for the response, what way would you recommend using?

Comment: I've attempted to implement the "def save" function, do I have to call that function in my views?

Comment: `save` will be fired automatically when you try to save an instance of your Model

Comment: Hmm, when 'cv' is displayed, it does not have the content of the file.

Comment: Try to change `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` to `super(Clean, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'. This is at 'get_text = self.cvfile.open().read()'

Comment: I tested the first approach and it works perfectly with a little change `cv = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank = True, null = True)`

Comment: I have changed this and migrated the db. However I still get a none type error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: I have reproduced this error in a fresh project. Traceback is posted above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170554/discussion-between-messaoud-zahi-and-yunter).